# Como funções Javascript se comportam em relação ao escopo?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, funções, escopo-de-variáveis

Em Javascript, funções são objetos e podem se passadas como parâmetro para outras funções. Mas e quando uma função com dependências em um objeto, como variáveis e outras funções, é passada para outro objeto ? Ela executa sempre a partir do primeiro objeto ? E se eu quisesse que a função acessasse propriedades do segundo objeto ? O código abaixo imprime "primeiro objeto".

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 objeto = new Obj1();
 objeto.passa();
});

function Obj1(){
 var texto = "Primeiro Objeto";
 var minhaFunc = function(){
  document.write(texto);
 }
 var objeto = new Obj2();

 this.passa = function(){
  objeto.setFunc(minhaFunc);
  objeto.exec();
 }
}

function Obj2(){
 var texto = "Segundo Objeto";
 var minhaOutraFunc;
 
 this.setFunc = function(func){
  minhaOutraFunc = func;
 }
 
 this.exec = function(){
  minhaOutraFunc.call();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mais especificamente..Você desejaria o que com essa funções? Um métodos que imprimisse algo direfente, como o da primeira função?

Comment: Imaginei que, como a função é passada para o segundo objeto, ela imprimiria a variável "texto" do segundo objeto.

Comment: Hum.. entendi.. existe algumas explicações para isso. Tentarei juntá-las em uma resposta :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pergunta interessante.

Considera o seguinte exemplo:

```
function a() {
    console.log('a', this);
}

function Obj() {
    var b = function() {
        console.log('b', this);
    }
    this.c = function() {
        console.log('c', this);
    }
    b();
    this.c();
}

function d() {
    function e() {
        console.log('e', this)
    }
    e();
}

a();
var o = new Obj();
o.c.call(window);
d();
```

Isto vai dar:

```
a Window
b Window
c Obj {}
c Window
e window
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/m6faf374/)

Sempre que declaras uma função o contexto de execução depende de alguns fatores. Se a função não fôr propriedade de um objeto ela vai correr com contexto global (casos a, b, e). Quando uma função é uma propriedade de um objeto então o contexto da função é esse objeto. Funções sem contexto defenido (ie que não são propriedade de nenhum objeto) correm contexto global.

Escopo e contexto são coisas diferentes. O escopo faz com que `b` seja um método privado do objeto, ie não disponível fora dele. O contexto tem a ver com o `this` dentro dessa função e o que ele é num dado contexto/momento.

Para mudar o contexto de uma função pode usar-se alguns métodos:

- `.bind(novoContexto)` que não invoca a função, muda somente o contexto
- `.call(novoContexto, arg1, arg2, etc)` este método invoca a função
- `.apply(novoContexto, [array com argumentos])` também invoca a função

Voltando ao teu exemplo imagina que o cenário era este (https://jsfiddle.net/zL9mroqm/), ou seja todas as funções e o texto estão ligados ao contexto de execução.

```
function Obj1() {
    this.texto = "Primeiro Objeto";
    this.minhaFunc = function() {
        console.log(this.texto);
    }
    var objeto = new Obj2();
    this.passa = function() {
        objeto.setFunc(this.minhaFunc);
        objeto.exec();
    }
}

function Obj2() {
    this.texto = "Segundo Objeto";
    this.setFunc = function(func) {
        this.minhaOutraFunc = func;
    }
    this.exec = function() {
        this.minhaOutraFunc();
    }
}
```

Neste caso imprime `Segundo Objeto`. Se mudares `this.minhaOutraFunc();` para `this.minhaOutraFunc.call();` vai dar `undefined` porque estás a chamar/invocar a função sem contexto. Se usares `this.minhaOutraFunc.call(objeto);` vai dar `Primeiro Objeto` porque defeniste que o contexto é a instância do objeto 1 que criaste dentro do `.ready()`.

Comment: Só pra constar, eu adoro suas respostas. Como eu posso me tornar um mestre em JavaScript como você, @Sergio?

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida obrigado! Mas eu não sou mestre. Eu aprendi muito aqui, no SOen  e com a comunidade do MooTools onde participo ativamente. Para além disso estou atento no YouTube e no Google acerca de novos artigos que vou lendo. Às vezes as perguntas aqui obrigam-me a ler e aprender para responder melhor. Acho que o truque é estar sempre curioso.

Comment: Entendi, mas só uma  dúvida: Porque b não pertence ao objeto ? Achei que a diferença entre usar "var" ou "this" fosse que, no primeiro caso, a variável é privada e, no segundo, a variável é pública.

Comment: @Carlos essa diferênça é entre _escopo_ e _contexto_. O escopo faz com que `b` seja um método privado do objeto, ie não disponível fora dele. O contexto tem a ver com o `this` e o que ele é num dado contexto.

Answer (score 4):

Isso é uma questão de escopo puramente e de overwriting (sobrescrição), já que, em JavaScript, as funções e objetos podem ser manipuladas facilmente como variáveis.

Pra acessar o método ou propriedade só é preciso informar `objeto.propriedade` ou `objeto["propriedade"]`.

No seu exemplo você criou o objeto `objeto` ao criar um variável que recebe `Obj2()`. Pra acessar o texto de `Obj2()` no objeto `Obj1()`, você só precisaria de um `objeto.texto`.

Dentro de um objeto você tem que colocar a palavra-chave `this` ao declarar campos: `this.texto;` e ao se referir ao campo fora do objeto: `objeto.texto`

Se quiser trabalhar com herança, você pode dar uma olhada nos métodos `.call()` e `prototype`.

Seu código acessando o texto de `Obj2()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  objeto = new Obj1();
  objeto.passa();
});

function Obj1() {
  var objeto = new Obj2();
  this.texto = "Primeiro Objeto";
  var minhaFunc = function() {
    document.write(objeto.texto);
  }
  this.passa = function() {
    objeto.setFunc(minhaFunc);
    objeto.exec();
  }
}

function Obj2() {
  this.texto = "Segundo Objeto";
  var minhaOutraFunc;
  this.setFunc = function(func) {
    minhaOutraFunc = func;
  }

  this.exec = function() {
    minhaOutraFunc.call();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seguindo por partes:

Primeiro, a sua variável `objeto` presente no `$(document).ready(...` não possui o `var` logo ela declarada no escopo global (reutilizável em todas as funções dentro do script), essa variável receberá o `new Obj1()`, que é uma função no escopo.

Dentro da `Obj1()` existe:

```
var minhaFunc = function(){
    document.write(texto);
}
```

Vamos deixar ela quieta, voltaremos a ela posteriormente.

Em outro momento do código da função `Obj1()`, nela há uma nova declaração da variável `objeto`, porém desta vez com a utilização do `var`, ou seja, está restrita a essa função, qualquer chamada a ela **dentro dessa função** receberá, ao invés de `Obj1()` o `Obj2()`.

Logo após temos:

```
this.passa = function(){
    objeto.setFunc(minhaFunc);
    objeto.exec();
}
```

A função `passa()`, chama a var `objeto`, que neste momento refere-se a função `Obj2()`, função a qual possui outra "subfunção" a `setFunc()`:

```
this.setFunc = function(func){
    minhaOutraFunc = func;
}
```

Essa função recebe como um parâmetro/argumento uma outra *function* que será armazenada na *var* `minhaOutraFunc`, sabendo que ela pertence a `Obj2()`. Mas no `Obj1()` passamos a ela o `minhaFunc()`:

```
    objeto.setFunc(minhaFunc);
```

Ou seja, a `var minhaOutraFunc` no `Obj2()` agora possui a `minhaFunc()`, já dita anteriormente ("voltaremos a ela posteriormente"). Esta irá imprimir na tela *"Primeiro Objeto"*.

Mas dentro da função `passar()`, também há:

```
objeto.exec();
```

O `exec()` no `Obj2()` é uma função que executa a *var* `minhaOutraFunc`, lembra que esta possui a `minhaFunc()` que pertence ao `Obj1()` e que nele escreve na tela este texto? Pois é. Olhe:

```
this.exec = function(){
    minhaOutraFunc.call();
}
```

O grande problema foi porque a `var texto` dentro de cada Obj, está declarada dentro de cada função **restriva**, devido ao uso do `var`.

Por isso ao executar uma função dentro do escopo de cada função, a variável texto fará correspondência a função em questão.

Exatamente por isso, imprime-se na tela o texto da da função `Obj1()`.

### Mas, e se eu quisesse, nesse caso, escrever o texto do *Obj2()*

Bastaria declarar, a variável `texto`, no escopo global, ou seja, sem o uso do `var`. Olhe:

```js
var objeto;
$(document).ready(function(){
 objeto = new Obj1();
 objeto.passa();
});

var texto;

function Obj1(){
 texto = "Primeiro Objeto";
 var minhaFunc = function(){
  document.write(texto);
 }
 var objeto = new Obj2();

 this.passa = function(){
  objeto.setFunc(minhaFunc);
  objeto.exec();
 }
}

function Obj2(){
 texto = "Segundo Objeto";
 var minhaOutraFunc;
 
 this.setFunc = function(func){
  minhaOutraFunc = func;
 }
 
 this.exec = function(){
  minhaOutraFunc.call();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Isso acontece porque dentro do `$(document).ready(...` a última execução é a da função `passa()` do `Obj1()`. E a última execução dentro dessa função, é a o chamado da escrita na tela, como o que será escrito é a variável `texto` e a última declaração dela **dentro do escopo global** (já que dessa vez foi declarada sem o `var`) foi feita no `Obj2()`, será impresso o que está nessa função.

E outra coisa, uma variável  por mais que sua chamada/utilização não seja com `var`, para ser considerada global, deve ser declarada sim com o `var`, porém no escopo em que se queira reutilizar, no global, ou em uma função. Isso também vale para a variável `objeto` no início de seu código.

#### E porque funcionou na situação anterior?

O javascript vai tentar lhe a dar quantidade menor possível de erros, principalmente quando falamos de reutilização de variáveis. Por isso que não precisamos determinar seu tipo, por isso que podemos fazer coisas como essa:

```
"5" * 8; // 40
```

**Informação relevante dentro de todo esse texto:** sempre que executar códigos que envolvam variáveis, sua execução vai levar em consideração a última declaração dessas variáveis.