# Qual a diferença entre this e var dentro de uma classe JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções

[image: Código com as três dúvidas]

me indiquem qual deles deve-se usar, quais são utilizados em boas práticas de programação. Escrevo em javascript mas costumo utilizar um e outro no mesmo código... Eae?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow O contexto daquela pergunta é outro, é sobre quando usar `var` versus omitir o `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença está nas instâncias que você cria dessa ["classe"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108548/existe-classe-em-javascript). A instância só expõe o que estiver no `this` dela ou tiver sido [herdado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript):

```
var objeto = new Func(); 
objeto.fn_this();    // "this"
objeto.fn_func();    // ERRO - objeto.fn_func is not a function
objeto.fn_var();     // ERRO - objeto.fn_var is not a function
```

Então basicamente você deve colocar no `this` o que você quer que seja exposto (mas muitas vezes é melhor colocar no protótipo). As outras duas formas você usa para aquilo que é "privado", que só pode ser acessado no [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108731/como-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-javascript-se-comportam-em-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-escopo) do construtor.

Vale entender também [a diferença entre `function fn(){}`  e `var fn = function(){}`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-var-name-function-e-function-name), e ainda [por que `fn_func` e `fn_var` podem ser chamadas de dentro de `fn_this`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript). Ver também: [O que é e como funciona o contexto no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8975/o-que-%C3%A9-e-como-funciona-o-contexto-no-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

O operador `this` sempre irá pegar o operador pai. Caso o pai não seja definido por padrão ele será o objeto `window`.

O `var`, como o próprio nome já indica, é uma variavel. Porém ele pode receber objetos e funções.

Quando você declara uma função em Javascript, você pode fazer ela normalmente com o `function` ou usar o `var fn = function() {}`. Dessa forma dizemos que a váriavel fn recebe uma função, e para poder usa-lá seria `fn();`.

Quando este está dentro de um objeto, a referencia será para o próprio objeto, porém temos que ter cuidado com o escopo. Se ele está em uma função a referência será a função. Por isso você pode encontrar por ai códigos usando o `var self = this;` para a referência ainda continuar na classe.