# Bind JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Escrevi este código como estudo para o entendimento do bind.
Crio um método em um objeto e tento chama-lo mudando o scope para outro objeto.

```
let car = {
  sound: 'Vrrrrummm',
  startEngine: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
  }
}

let bike = {
  sound: "Papapapapapapraprap"
}

car.startEngine.bind(bike)
```

Me ajudem a resolver ou explicar caso eu tenha entendido errado o conceito do bind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando usas o `.bind()` ele gera uma nova função com um novo contexto de execução. O `.bind()` só por si não corre/invoca a função. Acho que pretendes usar o `.call()` ou o `.apply()` neste caso, para invocar a função com um contexto de execução novo.

Dá uma olhada a [este exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/44zhvjzf/) com `.call()`:

```js
let car = {
  sound: 'Vrrrrummm',
  startEngine: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
  }
}

let bike = {
  sound: "Papapapapapapraprap"
}

car.startEngine.call(bike);
```

Para fazer o mesmo com `.bind()` terias de fazer algo assim:

```js
let car = {
  sound: 'Vrrrrummm',
  startEngine: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
  }
}

let bike = {
  sound: "Papapapapapapraprap"
}

let minhaFuncao = car.startEngine.bind(bike);
minhaFuncao();
```

Assim crias uma nova função e depois corrres essa função.

Nota:

Contexto e escopo são coisas diferentes. Podes dar uma [olhada a esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108745/129), mas basicamente contexto é o `this` quando a função corre, escopo é que variáveis fora da função estão acessíveis à função.

Comment: Muito bom. O bind somente muda o contexto, por isso a linha let minhaFuncao = car.startEngine.bind(bike) não faz nada. Obrigado, ajudou muito.

Answer (score 6):

Seu código está certo, só faltou você invocar o método. Para isso eu adicionei a invocação (`()`) no final do seu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A seguir a versão funcional:

```js
let car = {
  sound: 'Vrrrrummm',
  startEngine: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
  }
}

let bike = {
  sound: "Papapapapapapraprap"
}

car.startEngine.bind(bike)()
```

Comment: Sua resposta é coerente porém acredito que nesse caso se adeque melhor o cal() como disse o Sergio

Answer (score 2):

`Function#bind(instância, ...argumentos)` retorna uma função, que chama outra função, com instância e argumentos memorizados (incluindo que ainda podem ser passados + argumentos ao chamá-la).

Seria mais fácil ter usado `Function#call(instância, argumentos)` nesse contexto:

```
car.startEngine.call(bike)
```

(Isso faz com que o `this` de um novo escopo de uma função seja referência à `bike`.)