# Perda de referência em chamada de função

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Cenário:

```
class ClassName {

    constructor(service, params) {
        this.service = service;
        this.params = params;

        this.save(params.id);
    }

    save(id) {
        const { service, onSuccess, onError } = this;

        return service.save({ id }).then(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    onSuccess() {
        //do something
    }

    onError() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Explicação:

No **contructor** os parâmetros são recebidos e atribuídos ao **this** ocorrendo também a chamada da função **save**.

Durante a função **save** os valores de **this** são extraídos em **const** e o service **save** é executado retornando a função **onSuccess**, ou, em caso de falha, a função **onError**.

Problema:

As funções **OnSuccess** e **onError** não são executadas após o retorno do service (aparecem como "undefined" durante a execução de TDD), por perda de referência.

Uma solução encontrada:

Chamar as funções **onSuccess** e **onError** com *arrow function* da seguinte forma:

```
.then(() => this.onSuccess(), () => this.onError());
```

As dúvida são:

- Por que ocorreu essa perda de referência?
- Por que a utilização de *arrow functions* sanou o problema?
- Haveria outra forma de contornar essa perda de referência no exemplo acima?

Comment: Boa tarde Dorival, apenas para esclarecer: as funções `onSuccess` e `onError` não estão sendo executadas, ou são executadas sem a referência da classe?

Comment: Boa tarde @mrlew, as funções não são executadas no primeiro caso por falta de referência, o que não acontece no segundo com o uso de arrow function, sendo assim, neste segundo caso elas executam normalmente. Mas, exitem casos em que funções podem ser executadas sem referência?

Comment: Pergunta interessante! Relacionada com: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108745/129. Estou com pressa mas respondo mais logo.

Comment: Beleza! Fico no aguardo e obrigado por compartilhar o link Sergio

Comment: @DorivalZanetto o seu service está retornando uma Promise conforme a documento no https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise ? Pois fiz um teste e o resultado foi esperado conforme o cenário original.

Comment: Outras duas soluções, caso esteja usando babel habilitando o `stage-2` das propostas novas. https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator e https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields

Comment: @DorivalZanetto deixei resposta e fui dando uns retoques. Era essa informação que procuravas?

Comment: Sim @Sergio, foi bem esclarecedor. Parabéns pelos conteúdos apresentados na resposta e obrigado!

Comment: Estou usando o babel como transpile sim e vou dar uma nos links, obrigado @GabrielKatakura!

Comment: Mais uma solução: http://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/javascript-es7-function-bind-syntax/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso é um problema comum, que pode resolver-se com *arrow functions* ou com `.bind()`.

## Resumido:

**a) Porque ocorreu essa perda de referência?**

Quando corremos uma função como callback de uma Promise o contexto de execução (o `this`) muda para `undefined` ou o objeto global (`window` no browser).

**b) Por que a utilização de arrow functions sanou o problema?**

Essa é uma das novidades (nova possibilidade) com *arrow function*, ela corre no contexto de onde é declarada.

**c) Haveria outra forma de contornar essa perda de referência no exemplo acima?**

Sim, podes usar o [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) para forçar o contexto de execução. O `.bind()` cria uma cópia da função, sem a invocar, e quando ela fôr chamada corre com o contexto defenido no `.bind(contexto)`.

Exemplo:

```
return service.save({ id }).then(this.onSuccess.bind(this), this.onError.bind(this));
```

## Explicação mais alongada:

O contexto de execução de uma função depende de várias coisas. Regra geral diz-se que o contexto de execução é o objeto/classe ao qual a função pertence. [Falei sobre isso noutra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108745/129). No caso de funções normais um exemplo pode ser:

Exemplo:

```js
function teste() {
  console.log('contexto de teste é foo?:', this == 'foo');
  log();
}

function log() {
  console.log('contexto de log é foo?:', this == 'foo');
}

teste.call('foo');
```

Apesar da função `teste` correr num contexto próprio, `log` vai correr no contexto de execução `window`.

Funções passadas como callback a uma Promise são executados noutro contexto de execução. Assim, passar uma função como callback para o `.then()` não garante o contexto de execução. Isso não se aplica a *arrow functions* declaradas inline.

A Promise têm dois modos de operar no que diz respeito ao contexto de execução da callback:

- se estiver em `strict mode`

Caso estejamos em `strict mode` ou a função usada como callback implemente `strict mode`, então o `this` será `undefined`. Este é o teu caso, pois métodos de classes ES6 correm sempre em `strict mode`.

- se não estiver em `strict mode`

Caso não estejamos em `strict mode` nem a função usada como callback implemente `strict mode`, então o contexto de execução será o objeto global, window no caso do browser.

```js
class Classe {
  constructor(){
    this.teste();
    Promise.resolve().then(this.teste);
    }
  teste() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

new Classe();
```

**b) Por que a utilização de arrow functions sanou o problema?**

Esta é uma das vantagens e diferenças entre funções que já conhecemos, declaradas com `function`. A *arrow function*  vai sempre ter como contexto de execução o contexto envolvente onde está inserida.

Exemplo:

```
class Classe {
    constructor() {
        const logA = () => {
            console.log('logA', this);
        };
        const logB = function() {
            console.log('logB', this);
        }
        logA();
        logB();
    }
}

const logC = () => {
    console.log('logC', this);
};
const logD = function() {
    console.log('logD', this);
}
new Classe();
logC();
logD();
```

Neste exemplo ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tesg14yg/)) os resultados são:

```
logA // dá Classe {}
logB // undefined
logC // window
logD // undefined
```

Ou seja, *arrow functions* usam o contexto à sua volta, enquanto que  funções "à moda antiga" recebem o contexto do objeto a que pertencem.

Answer (score -2):

O código do cenário está correto, não deveria haver perda de referência se o serviço implementar corretamente o Promise conforme a padronização do [es6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects).
Assim para usar o then(), o método save() da classe service deve retornar um objeto Promise. A documentação do [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) tem um boa explicação. 
Provavelmente pode existir algum problema na implementação do objeto Promise retornado pelo service ou na chamada da função de onSuccess ou onError.

Exemplo:

```
class MyService {

  save(id) {

     console.log("Saving "+id);
     return Promise.resolve("Record id "+id+" saved!");

  }

}
```

Abaixo um link com o [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/divkey/g5nj3cn9/3/) funcionando que funciona caso o navegador implementar o es6.

Observação: Veja neste [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) a lista de navegadores implementam a especificação es6. Se o navegador não suportar a especificação do Promise é possível adicionar um pollyfill.

Comment: O problema é que esses métodos `onSucess` e `onError` são chamados com um contexto de execução que já não é a classe. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/g5nj3cn9/4/  e ao erro que isso gera por falta de `.bind(this)`

Comment: @Sergio concordo com você, caso se tivesse especificado os métodos onSuccess e onError. Ocorre que o desenvolvedor com menos conhecimento veria como obrigatório a necessidade de se utilizar as _arrow functions_ em qualquer then() de uma Promise. O código apresentado não possui nenhuma necessidade de adição desse recurso. Acredito que a pergunta deveria ser editada para melhor esclarecimento dos usuários.

Comment: @DorivalZanetto é quebrado mesmo, para mostrar que o `this` é errado. Fiz assim quebrado de propósito, só para exemplo.