# O que diferencia uma arrow function de uma função, digamos, "classica"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Comecei um curso de nodejs e o instrutor disse que o seguinte código:

```
modules.exports.addNote = function(){}
```

Seria substituído por:

```
modules.exports.addNote = () => {}
```

Qual seria a diferença de uma pra outra e por que usar uma e não outra?

Comment: E também relacionada: [Perda de referência em chamada de função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178215/129)

Comment: @Mariano boa! obrigado