# this.test1 is undefined

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, input, construtor

Estou tentando passar minha aplicação para o paradigma **OO**, porém na hora de pegar o valor do input é retornado *undefined*.

Eu queria saber o **porquê** que é apresentado esse erro, sendo que o *addEventListener*  continua funcionando e como eu poderia resolver.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.test1 = document.getElementById("test");
  }

  method(e) {
    let varTest1 = this.test1.value;
    console.log(varTest1);
  }
  
  methodRun(e) {
    this.test1.addEventListener("change", this.method);
  }
}

let run = new Test();
run.methodRun();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="test">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Porque você esta passando o método diretamente, e assim não receberá a referencia, é como se você tivesse enviado apenas o a parte que é "function" do método, mas não esta "passando" a relação com a classe instanciada.

Você pode resolver com `() =>`:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.test1 = document.getElementById("test");
  }

  method(e) {
    let vatTest1 = this.test1.value;

    console.log(vatTest1);
  }
  
  methodRun(e) {
    var _self = this;

    this.test1.addEventListener("change", () => this.method());
  }
}

let run = new Test();
run.methodRun();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="test">
</body>

</html>
```

Ou com `function () {}`:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.test1 = document.getElementById("test");
  }

  method(e) {
    let vatTest1 = this.test1.value;

    console.log(vatTest1);
  }
  
  methodRun(e) {
    var _self = this;

    this.test1.addEventListener("change", function () {
         _self.method();
    });
  }
}

let run = new Test();
run.methodRun();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="test">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: perdão pela ingenuidade, mas não entendi muito bem ainda, principalmente a parte do var _self = this e a parte de enviar a parte que é "function" do método.

Comment: @JoãoVítor o function () {} tem escopo separado, o this não é uma variavel, portanto para passar para outro escopo tem que setar em uma var. Ou então use arrow function () => que trata tudo no mesmo escopo.

Comment: sabe dizer se há outra forma de resolver esse problema? ainda estou um pouco confuso aqui.

Comment: @JoãoVítor é exatamente isso que apresentei na resposta, para passar o método precisa passar o objeto instanciado, você esta usando OO em um código JS, é assim que se resolve, passando para o outro contexto... outro meio de resolver é não usar OO sem necessidade, na verdade a maior parte do uso de OO é desnecessário, alguém inventou que OO era solução mágica para tudo, o que não é verdade. O que recomendo é que você aprenda o que é escopo, então vai ficar mais óbvio aonde você precisa melhorar.

Comment: @JoãoVítor leia [Perda de referência em chamada de função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178215/100416) e [Qual a diferença entre function() {} e () => {}?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143399/100416)

Answer (score -2):

Achei uma outra solução que consegui entender melhor.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.test1 = document.getElementById("test");
  }

  method(e) {
    let _self = new Test();
    let varTest1 = _self.test1.value;
    console.log(varTest1);
  }
  
  methodRun(e) {
    this.test1.addEventListener("change", this.method);
  }
}

let run = new Test();
run.methodRun();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="test">
</body>

</html>
```