# Entendendo este uso do addEventListener no Cordova

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

Olá, estudando um pouco sobre o Cordova e o PhoneGap, especificamente o aplicativo padrão, HelloWorld, observei a linha: document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false); a qual fica em um arquivo js (index.js). Então, até onde eu sei, o addEventListener, pelo que vi no W3School, ele tem o evento como o primeiro parâmetro, a função como o segundo, e um booleano opcional como terceiro. Mas no exemplo que coloquei, o 'deviceready' que é o elemento, está no lugar do evento? É isso? e esse "this" no parâmetro: "thisonDeviceReady". Pois já usei várias vezes o addEventListener assim: [document.getElementById('elementox').addEventlistener('click',myfunction); Por isso eu não entendi. Peço ajuda quanto a isso. Penso que a resposta/explicação, pode estar no próprio código (comentado) do PhoneGap, porém, além de estar em inglês, eu vi e revi, mas não consegui entender.

Eis os códigos:

```js
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Na questão `deviceready` é o evento e `this.onDeviceReady` é a função que esta logo abaixo. [Como funções Javascript se comportam em relação ao escopo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108731)

Comment: NoobSaibot... então, pelo que pesquisei,  não existe evento onDeviceReady na lista de eventos do Javascript! E como o exemplo pode usar tal evento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. Realmente, o evento "deviceready" é próprio (específico) do Cordova, portanto, não faz parte da lista de eventos do Javascript. E este evento é para duas coisas principais: certificar que o dispositivo acionado pelo Cordova é um mobile, e certificar que os plugins Cordova foram carregados e já estão disponíveis na memória para chamadas. Obrigado a todos.